# how do i know image position relative to the container so i can know whether to disable animation control

Tags: jquery, html

i have an image inside a div where the image is wider than the div and the div is set to overflow:hidden.

I create a control to slide the image each time the control is clicked.

How do i know that there is no more part of the image left in the right side for example so that i can disable the control?

```
            <div class="timeLineDiv">
            <img class="aboutusTimelineImage" src="imageurl"  />
            </div>
            <div class="timelineControlDiv">
                <div class="timelineControlLeft"><</div>                    
                <div class="timelineControlRight">></div>
            </div>
```

the js is

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".timelineControlLeft").click(function () {
                    var a = $(".aboutusTimelineImage").position();
                    $(".aboutusTimelineImage").animate({ left: '-=100px' }, "slow");
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a width of image and his position, so you can calculate distance on the left or right side `outside the div` and block or start an animation.